# Create nuget package that include other nuget package

Tags: reference, nuget, nuget-package, packagereference

I have created a **.NET Standard** project where I installed the version `4.4.4` of the `System.ServiceModel.Http` nuget package. This package include also the dll `System.ServiceModel.Primitives`... I add image:

[image]

I have created a nuget package from my project with the command

```
.\nuget.exe pack MyProjectFile.csproj -Build -ExcludeEmptyDirectories -IncludeReferencedProjects -OutputDirectory  MyOutputDir
```

Now I must install this package in another solution, in a **.NET Framework** project. But for some reason when I start the project I obtain this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel.Primitives,
>   Version=4.2.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies.

The versione `4.2.0.3` of the dll `System.ServiceModel.Primitives` is inside the package version `4.4.4`

I have edited my .NET Standard project file in this way:

```
<PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Primitives" Version="4.4.4" />
<PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="4.4.4" />
```

But when I install the package in my .NET Project I still receive that error. No external package has been included in my package... What do I miss?

Thank you

**EDIT**

I also expected, when I install my nuget package, a window appear and tell me something like "You need to install also the Package A and the Package B. Continue or not?". Nothing appear instead....

Comment: try including `System.ServiceModel.Primitives` manually

Comment: still does not work... always same error

Comment: I resolved... It seems that .NET Standard Projects ignore `PackageReference` in the project file and they still need `nuspec` file

Comment: check my solution. I have `PackageReference` included automatically all the time.

Comment: As Neville answered below, you should use `dotnet pack` to pack SDK projects, rather than `nuget.exe`. It generates the nuspec for you, including dependencies. If you don't use `System.ServiceModel.Primites` directly, I don't recommend adding it as a project reference. Let NuGet get transient dependencies automatically when needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .net standard projects, you can use the dotnet CLI instead of nuget.exe. I always found it cleaner and a far lesser process. You can use something like this with the dotnet CLI

```
dotnet pack -c release -o MyOutputDir
```

Here output folder is optional and config would be "debug" by default. I have used this for several nugets and I never have an issue with nuget references.

Comment: clarification: SDK projects. It's possible to use SDK projects to target .NET Framework, and take advantage of multi-targeting and packing. It's not limited to .NET Standard or .NET Core.